# iOS app crashes when firebase query limit exceeds 9

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Just like the title says, I make a call to firebase database with a query return limit of 9 and the app runs without crashing. But when I increase the number to 10 it suddenly crashes. I have no idea why.

Here is the function called in the view controller

```
func loadPosts() {
    isLoadingPost = true
    Api.Feed.getRecentFeed(withId: Api.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid, start: posts.first?.timestamp, limit: 9  ) { (results) in
        if results.count > 0 {
            results.forEach({ (result) in
                self.posts.append(result.0)
                self.users.append(result.1)
            })
        }
        self.isLoadingPost = false
        if self.refreshControl.isRefreshing {
            self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        }
        self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    Api.Feed.observeFeedRemoved(withId: Api.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid) { (post) in
        self.posts = self.posts.filter { $0.id != post.id }
        self.users = self.users.filter { $0.id != post.uid }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Here is the function in its class

```
func getRecentFeed(withId id: String, start timestamp: Int? = nil, limit: UInt, completionHandler: @escaping ([(Post, UserModel)]) -> Void) {

    var feedQuery = REF_FEED.child(id).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")
    if let latestPostTimestamp = timestamp, latestPostTimestamp > 0 {
        feedQuery = feedQuery.queryStarting(atValue: latestPostTimestamp + 1, childKey: "timestamp").queryLimited(toLast: limit)
    } else {
        feedQuery = feedQuery.queryLimited(toLast: limit)
    }

    // Call Firebase API to retrieve the latest records
    feedQuery.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let items = snapshot.children.allObjects
        let myGroup = DispatchGroup()


        var results: [(post: Post, user: UserModel)] = []

        for (index, item) in (items as! [DataSnapshot]).enumerated() {
            myGroup.enter()
            Api.Post.observePost(withId: item.key, completion: { (post) in
                Api.User.observeUser(withId: post.uid!, completion: { (user) in
                    **results.insert((post, user), at: index)** //when limit is greater than 10 - app crashes here with exc_bad_instruction error
                    print(index)
                    myGroup.leave()
                })
            })
        }
        myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            results.sort(by: {$0.0.timestamp! > $1.0.timestamp! })
            completionHandler(results)
        }


    })

}
```

App crashes where the stars are when limit is above 9

Comment: Saying *it suddenly crashes* isn't very helpful. Have you added a breakpoint and stepped through the code until it crashes? How about a smattering of print statements to determine where the crash? It's important to include those details as without it we are just guessing.

Comment: The view itself will not load and cause a crash. App launches to the home screen fine, but when you go to the discover view (the one mentioned above) it crashes. The error I get is then exc_bad_instruction at the line which is highlighted above. I have added prints to no avail. The print line after the starred line prints a 0 as for the first index, but an error is still thrown.

Comment: As I mentioned above, adding a print statement would reveal a lot. Add print(post, user, index) right above the line that's crashing - that will tell you why it's crashing as one of those will probably be nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think of is that you have observe in the `Api.Post.observePost` instead of a single observe so after the last leave occurs the completion is called  , then another call to this line happens

```
results.insert((post, user), at: index)
```

when that array

```
var results: [(post: Post, user: UserModel)] = []
```

isn't exists because of de-allocation